# How to execute a function when the scroll reaches an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide all elements but the first one so I use `$(".item:not(:eq(0))").fadeOut();`

I have elements with the same class "item":

```
<div class="item">First Item</div>
<div class="item">Second Item</div>
<div class="item">Third Item</div>
<div class="item">Fourth Item</div>
```

Then when I scroll to the next element which could be "second , third,fourth item" , I want to show it

I tried using :

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{

 var centerY = Math.max(0,((jQuery(window).height()- 
                  jQuery(elem).outerHeight()) / 2) 
                  + jQuery(window).scrollTop());

    var elementTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return elementTop <= centerY && elementBottom >= centerY;
    }


    jQuery(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
        jQuery(".news:not(:eq(0))").each(function(index, element) {
            if (isScrolledIntoView(element)) {
               jQuery(element).fadeIn(10000);
            }
        });
    });
```

But it doesn't work with my method because the height of the body changes on showing the next item "Second Item" , So All the items are shown when I scroll to the "Second Item" or any other item.

How to hide the items but the first one and then `fadIn()` each on scrolling to it ?

Comment: Capture the initial scroll height after hiding the elements (assuming 0), then capture onscroll and show each element based on the amount of scroll, using something like `$('.item:hidden:first').fadeIn();` e.g. every 10 pixels of scroll show the next hidden item.

Comment: How do  you scroll into second, third, fourth items if these divs are `fadeOut` already....be more clear what you exactly want..?

Comment: I gave the body a height so I could scroll

Answer (score 0):

> This is using `offset()` in jquery. This demo will trigger function if
>   your element is completely in your viewport.

*Tip:You need to take care of inner as well as outer height of element.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
height:200vh;
}
#test {
  top: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>scroll to test</p>

<div id="test">
  <p>Click the button to get offsetTop for the test div.</p>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var x = $("#test").offset();
        var height1 = $("#test").outerHeight();
        var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var z = (x.top + height1) - y;
        if(z < $(window).height()){
             alert("fumction");
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be more easy to use the combination of waypoint.js and animate.css. 
Add animated class to every element to be animated. You can use any of the animate.css effects.
Change the offset { offset: '80%' } to control when the animation can start.

```
<div class="animated waypoint-slideup">

</div>

$('.waypoint-slideup').waypoint(function () {
    $(this).addClass('slideInUp');
}, { offset: '80%' });
```

Use this in the css file

```
.waypoint-slideup{
opacity:0;}
.waypoint-slideup.slideInUp{
opacity:1;}
```